# PHP Mongodb create Text Index

Tags: php, mongodb, indexing

I am new in MongoDB, and I'm trying to create a text index.
After trying several hours, I have not accomplished anything.

I have an `array` like this:

```
//The keys and values are reversed to avoid duplicates in the array keys.
$arr = array(
    'Personal' => array(
                            'PEPE' => "_id",
                            'd' => array(
                                        "full_name" => "Pedro",
                                        "last_name" => "Picapiedras",
                                        "address"=> "La matanza 123",
                                        "department"=> "Soporte"
                                ), //d end
                            'PABLO' => "_id",
                            'd' => array(
                                        "full_name"=> "Pablo",
                                        "last_name"=> "Marmolejo",
                                        "address"=> "Pica  123",
                                        "department"=> "Soporte"
                                ), //d end
        )//personal end
    );//arr end
```

I want to create an Index of the `_id` field so that to edit or view documents, access them through "Pablo" or "Pepe".

Is this possible? Could you give me a hand on how I can do this?

**Edit**

I have tried with

```
db.reviews.createIndex( { comments: "text" } )
```

and

```
$user = Array(
        '_id'  => "$id",
        'name' => $name,
    ); 
   $query = Array( '_id' => "$id" );
   $query = Array( '_id' => new MongoId("$id") );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It makes it easier for people to help you if you have code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $arr = array(
  'PEPE' => array(
    "_id" => 'PEPE',
    'd' => array(
      "full_name" => "Pedro",
      "last_name" => "Picapiedras",
      "address" => "La matanza 123",
      "department" => "Soporte"
    ) //d end
  ), //PEPE END  
  'PABLO' => array(
    "_id" => 'PABLO',
    'd' => array(
      "full_name" => "Pablo",
      "last_name" => "Marmolejo",
      "address" => "Pica  123",
      "department" => "Soporte"
    ), //d end
  ) // Pablo END
); //$arr end


function insertMongo($array) {
  try {
    $mongo = new MongoClient();
    $db = $mongo -> dbName;
    $collection = $db -> collectionName;
    $collection -> insert($array);
  } catch (MongoCursorException $e) {
    die("Query failed ".$e - > getMessage());
  }

} //insertMongo


//To execute:
foreach($arr as $a) {
  insertMongo($a);
};
```

Comment: Maybe not the best for the performance, as there are about 150 records to insert and then be updated, but worked perfectly and if no other solution ...
Thank You!